# C# Set the Number of cells in DataGridView wile passing through forms?

Tags: c#, datagridview, visual-studio-2015

I am now attempting to got from Main Menu form (when button is clicked ) to a table setup form (with textbox and OK button) once a numver is entered into the textbox and OK is pressed i would then like my Datatableview form to load up and add the required (user input) rows to the Datatableview.  i have been googleing and searching around for ages but am struggling as im not finding alot of stuff on parsing from one for to the next and adding rows.

here is the code im trying to get working

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                int lines = Int32.Parse(linesReq.Text);

                if (lines != 0)
                {

                    Roster Roster = new Roster();
                    this.Hide();
                    Roster.dataGridView1.RowCount.Equals(lines);
                    Roster.ShowDialog();
                }
                else MessageBox.Show("No number entered in number of lines required! Please Enter the number of staff you have fort his roster and try again");
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show("Error from Roster Creation: Have you entered Number of Lines/Staff required for roster form?  " + ex); }
```

But as yet this will load the DataTableView form up but wont add any Rows to it. Any ideas? I am very new at C# so i may have missed something in the learning curve to this point.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try to do that :

```
Roster.dataGridView1.RowCount = lines;
```